# Javascript AddEventListener to local class instead of this

Tags: javascript

**Coming from C++ I am confused about the "this" keyword in Javscript.**

What I want to do is use the this keyword when I add an eventlistener in the subclass. However I've noticed this doesnt seem to work so I wonder how I'd make this work instead.

```
let myClass = new Class();
myClass.AddSubClass();

function Class()
{
    this.array = new Array();

  this.AddSubClass = function()
  {
    let sub = new SubClass();

    this.array.push(sub);
  }
}

function SubClass()
{
  let maindiv = document.getElementById("Main");
  this.btn = document.createElement("button");
  this.btn.innerHTML = "Button";
  this.btn.addEventListener("click", function() { this.Upgrade(); });

  maindiv.appendChild(this.btn);

  this.Upgrade = function()
  {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

This is some quick example that I wrote there might be error but it should still show what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm still **very new to Javscript** and trying to learn my way around.
Hopefully there is an easy answer to this.

What my error is that whenever I press the button. I get "this.Upgrade()" is not a function.

Comment: Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to improve it, for example by telling us *what happens* and *how* "this doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Can you please tell us a bit more on what is your desired output?

Comment: I hope when I press the button I run the Upgrade function of the created class. Not any other subclass created.

Comment: `addEventListener` binds element as context to callback. So you can create a variable `self` and use it instead of this and it will work. Since you are using `let`, arrow functions should also be fine. Using arrow function might also solve it, but I prefer using `self` instead

Comment: Do you mean like: var self = this; and then 
  this.btn.addEventListener("click", function() { self.Upgrade(); });?

Comment: @indiehjaerta Yup. Thats exactly what I mean

Comment: Okey thanks, it works perfectly so I'm happy with this answer. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an event handler, the `this` object is the object the handler is set on. In your case the `button` element.

To use the `SubClass` object, you need to use another variable, that in the constructor function is assigned a reference to the `SubClass` object:

```
function SubClass()
{
    // ...
    self = this;
    // ...
    this.btn.addEventListener("click", function() { self.Upgrade(); });
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in JS, `this` doesn't stick to the class it is defined in, but is context sensitive.

```js
function foo(label="") {
  console.log(label, this);
}

let a = {foo, id: "a"};
let b = {foo, id: "b"};

//usually "this" is the object the function is executed of
a.foo();
b.foo();

//you can also pass the context
var c = {id:"c"};
foo.call(c, "c");
foo.apply(c, ["here", "you", "can", "pass", "an", "array", "of", "arguments"]);

//you can bind it
var d = {foo: foo.bind(c), id:"d"};
d.foo("calling on 'd' but 'this' is still 'c':");

//if you just call the function, the context is the global object
foo("plain call:");
```

In your case, you'd have to either store the object in `this` or you can use an arrow function wich has no own `this`.

```
var _this = this;
this.btn.addEventListener("click", function() { _this.Upgrade(); });

this.btn.addEventListener("click", () => this.Upgrade() );
```

---

Sidenote, coming from C++: 
JS doesn't care about mismatching arguments when calling a function. If you pass too many arguments, the rest is ignored. If you pass to few, the remaininig arguments will be set to `undefined`.

Same for the return value, if your function doesn't explicitely return a value, it implicitely returns an `undefined` value.
Except for constuctor functions called with the `new` keyword, then you either return an object *(primitives are ignored)*, or the implicit retun value is `this`;